# LCD 2x16 I2C ST7032i

Tags: i2c, lcd

I write a code using Atmel ASF for SAM devices for LCD 2x16 with ST7032i controller.
I've encounter an issue about reading and specifically "busy flag reading".
How can i perform read instruction to get data?

LCD datasheet:
http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1811619.pdf
page 14

Answer (score 1):

As always, R/W is the last bit of the I<sup>2</sup>C slave address. From UM10204, section 3.1.10:

> After the START condition (S), a slave address is sent. This address is seven bits long followed by an eighth bit which is a data direction bit (R/W) — a ‘zero’ indicates a transmission (WRITE), a ‘one’ indicates a request for data (READ) [...].

How to access BF is given right in the paragraph describing the flag:

> BF can be read, when RS = Low and R/W = High (Read Instruction
>   Operation), through DB7 port.

Answer (score 0):

The controller that the LCD module uses has parallel and serial (I<sup>2</sup>C) buses. The module that uses the controller only brings out the I<sup>2</sup>C serial bus. Using the serial bus, it's not possible to do any read operations on that controller (see datasheet chapter 6, I2C Interface). So you'll just have to have sufficiently long delays in your code so that the controller is not busy when you write a new command to it. In practice, it's usually of no concern, since the I<sup>2</sup>C bus is so slow anyway, that I wouldn't see it possible to write commands to the controller too quickly using the I<sup>2</sup>C.

Comment: this mean that i cannot run read command to lcd? And how can i read busy flag? it's in the datasheet. It couldn't be there if there's no read instruction

Comment: Unfortunately it seems so. This is very common in simple LCD modules. You cannot read from it. There is a read instruction but it's only accessible from the parallel bus, not from the serial bus. And the parallel bus pins are probably somewhere below the LCD glass, often buried inside a mass of black epoxy.

Comment: I think that, RS bit signed via Control Byte which sended after Acknowledge in Reading mode.

Comment: I send [ADDRESS][R]_[A]_[CONTROL BYTE]. Control byte = 0 (Co=0, RS=0, and other bits 0) and in this point, lcd blocked, and needs reset after this.

Comment: Hmm... what do you mean "blocked"? Do you get ACKs from the LCD when you write the bytes?

Comment: i using a read command from Atmel Software Framework which can send 3byte of internal address before wants data to be read from slave address. and after this [ADDRESS][R]_[A]_[CONTROL BYTE] [read data] lcd blocked, no one command are performed and needs reset via RESET pin

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with that software framework, but I suspect that it may be that you can't use that software framework with that LCD screen. The command structure seems quite complex. I think that you should implement the I2C code by hand and take it one bit at a time. It's not very difficult and often a faster way to success than using someone else's code (in case the code is not applicable in the end, then you're just wasting time). But do you get anything on the screen, by the way :-) ?

Comment: i've acchieve to print strings on display. but i have trouble with read from it

Comment: Ok, ok then. I somehow thought you hadn't yet. Well, in that case then I think you've achieved all that you can with that display. This is copied+pasted directly from the datasheet, page 11: "I2C interface. It just only could write Data or Instruction to ST7032 by the IIC Interface. It could not read Data or Instruction from ST7032 (except Acknowledge signal)." (sic; the bad English is not mine)